# Single arrow at the end of a geom_bezier2 line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like a curved line with a color gradient from one end to the other and a single arrow at the end using `ggplot()`.

Using `geom_curve` I can get the correct curve and a nice looking arrow on the end. However, I haven't been able to add a color gradient to this. I am able to apply the color gradient and curve I am looking for by using `geom_bezier2` but it looks like there are multiple arrows layered on top of each other. Is there a way to achieve the `geom_bezier2` line with an arrow that looks like the `geom_curve` line?

```
#curved line with correct arrow but no color gradient
ggplot() +
  geom_curve(
    aes(x = -75, y = 42.5, xend = -85, yend = 30.5, size=3),
    curvature = -0.2, 
    lineend = "round",
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")))

#data frame for bezier
bezArrow <- data.frame(
  x = c(-75, -77, -85),
  y = c(42.5, 35, 30.5),
  color = c(3, 2, 1))

#curved line with color gradient but not the arrow I'm looking for
ggplot() +
  geom_bezier2(data = bezArrow, aes(x = x, y = y, color = color, linewidth = 3),
               lineend = 'round',
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"), ends = 'last')) +
  scale_color_gradient(high = 'grey', low = 'black')
```

[image: Curved line with proper arrow using geom_curve but no color gradient.][image: Curved line with proper gradient using geom_bezier2 but multiple arrows.]

Comment: where is `geom_bezier2` defined ... `ggforce`?

Comment: @r2evans `ggforce` is correct

Comment: Possibly a related issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really possible directly within ggforce, but you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggforce:::bezierPath(bezArrow$x, bezArrow$y, 100) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(x = V1, y = V2) %>%
  mutate(xend = lead(x), yend = lead(y),
         color = approx(bezArrow$x, bezArrow$color, xout = x)$y,
         alpha = c(rep(0, n() - 2), 1, 1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, xend = xend, yend = yend, color = color)) +
  geom_segment(size = 3, lineend = "round", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_segment(size = 3, lineend = "round", aes(alpha = alpha),
            arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm")), na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_color_gradient(high = 'grey', low = 'black') +
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @AllanCameron, this helps! However, I am a little confused what the code is doing. From what I understand, the first have is editing the data frame and the second half is plotting the line. Would you be able to explain how the curve is being created with `geom_segment`?

Comment: @VanessaNiemczyk the first half uses the same method as `geom_bezier2` to construct the co-ordinates of the path, breaking it into 100 tiny individual segments. This allows each little segment to get its own color, giving the illusion of a smooth gradient (again this is what `geom_bezier2` does under the hood). We then draw all these segments without an arrow. Finally, we draw them all again with arrows, but make them all invisible apart from the last segment.