# How to color many lines in a map with a gradient of colors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to color many lines in one map with a gradient of color that will change along the lines' length.  I want to start the line with a blue color and end (as can be seen by the arrow indication) with red.

I am currently using the following code:

```r
map_plot <- ggplot() +
            geom_sf(data = data, aes(geometry = geometry)) +
            geom_curve(data = data,
                       aes(x = Long_rea, y = Lat_rea, xend = Long_dest, yend = Lat_dest),
                       curvature = 0.3,
                       arrow = arrow(type = "open", length = unit(0.1, "inches"))) +
            labs(title = "Distance across the world", x = "", y = "") +
            theme_minimal()

# Display the map
print(map_plot)
```

The map is that:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackowerflow. Please provide a reproducible example so that the community could help you. Start with appending your question with thhe result of `dput(data)`

Comment: I don't think it's inherently possible with `geom_curve` (happy to be corrected) but for a possible workaround see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74353143/16730940

Comment: Tks Paul. Indeed, the geom_curve looks a bit hard to perform that task. Unfortunately, I am still not managing to execute the task.  Thank you for your reply

Comment: james, either provide a sample of your data here or use a public (likely `sf`-based) dataset for us to work with. Lacking that, figure out how to take each "line", break into 5 or 20 or 500 "segments" and color each segment yourself. This seems likely to benefit from `geosphere`, since I suspect you're looking for great-circle lines, not perfectly straight, but perhaps I'm wrong. Good luck.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73374250/cant-find-a-solution-for-color-the-month-in-line-graph-in-r) is a solution for a similar non-map based problem.  Until your question is reproducible, I can't suggest more.